# SQL - count recurrence on different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, count, multiple-columns, unpivot

i'm trying to find the total number of recurrences of all values on different columns.

For example:

[image: example]

Any advice? thanks

Comment: Hi, please include at least a draft of your code attempts to solve the problem

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Who designed that table?!?

Comment: Tag done. It's a table generated automatically from an excel sheet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpivot, then aggregate. If your database supports `values()` and lateral joins:

```
select x.name, count(*) cnt
from mytable
cross join lateral (values (name1), (name2), (name3)) as x(name)
group by x.name
```

A more portable (although less efficient) approach is `union all`:

```
select name, count(*) cnt
from (
    select name1 as name from mytable
    union all select name2 from mytable
    union all select name3 from mytable
) x
group by name
```

Comment: Thanks! the second one worked like a charm!! I'm using MySQL so i don't think i can use lateral join